# Not able to access .ToList() method on Table

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to use SilverlightPhoneDatabase to use a sqlite db for my Windows Phone 7 application.

The dll has a class Database

```
    public class Database
    {
    .
    .
    .
    public Table<T> Table<T>();
    .
    .
    }
```

Definition of class Table is as follows:

```
public class Table<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ITable
```

Then in my App.xaml
I have a method

```
 public static Database MyDB
 {
get
{
// Delay creation of the view model until necessary
if (database == null)
OpenDatabase<MyObj>("MyObj");
return database;
}
}
```

Now from my xaml.cs file I am able to access the .ToList() method on the Table.
ie If I say

`App.MyDB.Table<MyObj>().ToList();`

from my main.xaml.cs, I can access the ToList() method (Table class inherited from ObservableCollection..)

But I created a new class in a new cs in the same namespace.. and if I try to access the ToList() method on the Table class, I am getting compiler error that Table<> does not contain definition for 'ToList'

I am just curious why is it not working? It may be something silly I am missing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ToList` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` : [`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) so you need to add an using for the `System.Linq` namespace to be able to use it.

The compiler is basically rewriting

```
App.MyDB.Table<MyObj>().ToList();
```

as

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(App.MyDB.Table<MyObj>());
```

Comment: Yes that did it... It was strange.. There were no Resolve suggestions when I right click..

Comment: AFAIK you need ReSharper to have suggestion on the `using` you need to add to make an extension method works, visual studio doesn't provide them.